# wordpress theme not the same as advertised when applied

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I am trying to install the goodstore wordpress theme found here :

This is their menu :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzt8hhp0dvlpaul/Capture1.JPG?dl=0

This is how it looks when i apply it :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vgnn4ajjqboo5l/Capture.JPG?dl=0

What could course this? and what should i be looking for to resolve this issue?
wordpress version 4.0 ( same issue with lower versions)
woocommmerce 2.2
theme version 1.2.3( latest)

Comment: You should add some code to help other users to understand your question.

Comment: Well i am a complete monkey in wordpress. i dont know exactly what code to give. Is there anyway you could direct me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themes are generally pretty barebones until you customize the hell out of them. I haven't worked with this theme specifically but for starters you'll want to edit the Menu (which is just standard Wordpress functionality, nothing to do with your theme) to create the items you want in your navigation bar.

Many themes add new menus to the left sidebar; look there for additional customization options. WooCommerce adds its own set of menus that is independent of your theme.

Lastly, click on Appearance > Themes and hit the Customize button next to your theme for potentially even more appearance options (not all themes put options here).

Beyond that you might want to get a handle on working with basic Wordpress before trying to apply themes.